# How can I connect a Windows 7 and MacbookPro together on network to share files?

Tags: windows-7, networking, osx-snow-leopard, file-sharing

I have a Windows 7 and MacbookPro (SnowLeopard 2.6.4) connected on my home router.

How can I connect them over the network so I can easily share files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snow Leopard can connect to a Windows 7 SMB share.

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1568

Answer (score 0):

You could try: http://www.chungles.com/about.php

I have never used it, but it claims to be platform independent.

In case you would like to sync files across the two machines,
you could use DropBox.(http://www.dropbox.com/)
This is free up to 2GB. We use DropBox at our company and it is an excellent, seemless, backup and sync solution. It does a decent job of version control as well.